# Anyone has an example in Cypress that uses OneLogin?

Tags: node.js, authentication, cypress, onelogin

Pretty much that.
My company has some apps that are behind OneLogin authentication, which so far has been a pain to automate in Cypress.

The ideal result I imagine is having values for "user" and "password" in my project and use `cy.request()`to call OneLogin. From that I can extract a temporary access token and use it in a `cy.setCookie()` into my `beforeEach()`s.

I already can run tests with Cookies that I filled in manually.

If somebody already experienced the Cypress + OneLogin combo, please, share how you did it =).

Update:

I created this article on Medium with detailed explanation on how to do it, in case anyone needs it in the future:

https://medium.com/@jedicwb/cypress-io-onelogin-using-api-to-authenticate-before-testing-a6e2412b356c

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__single-sign-on might help give you an idea

Comment: Thanks @CoryDanielson, that helped a little.

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours (or days, not sure) of work, I finally managed it.

What I had to do, basically is:

1. Follow this instructions to [generate a token](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/oauth20-tokens/generate-tokens):
2. Then, follow this instructions to use that token and [get a session-token](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-login-token):
3. Then, this last step will [actually log you in](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/login-user-via-api) using that session token.

The catch is that after step 3 you can already use a `cy.visit()` to access any page that would require you to be logged in and it just works. Also, step 3 requires you to submit a FORM and not Json.

Just make sure to use `cy.request()` to make your API calls in every step.

It is quite a process, so I plan to create a Medium article soon to explain exactly how I did it. Soon.